# What should I take as virtual displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, work, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

> A bicycle rider has M. The wheels of the bicycle are at distance l apart and horizontal distance between the seat and the rear wheel is d. Use principle of virtual work to find the normal reactions on the base of the two wheels when the rider is riding steadily.

There are two constraints here

$x_{rider}-x_{rear}=d$

$x_{front}-x_{rear}=l$

Now to solve the question I need to take some virtual displacement and then apply the principle of virtual work , however I am not sure what should I take as virtual displacement. The only virtual displacement I can think of are the ones which are parallel to direction of motion, however they dont help to solve the question.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the ground is springy and take displacements in the vertical direction. The work done on the ground $-N_{\rm front} \delta h_{\rm front}- N_{\rm rear} \delta h_{\rm rear} $ plus the work done to change the height of the rider $Mg \,\delta h_{\rm rider}$ must be zero for all small $\delta h$'s. The only hard thing is the geometry involved  working out $\delta h_{\rm rider}$ in terms of $\delta h_{\rm rear}$ and $\delta h_{\rm front}$.

The fact that bike is moving is an irrelevent distraction.

Comment: But why do I need to assume ground is springy , Why can't I do it with a solid ground?

Comment: You can. But it is virtual work, mike is only mentioning that to aid understanding.

Comment: @Rescy_ Ok , but how can I do it considering ground to be solid because if I take any virtual displacement in vertical direction it would violate the condition of ground being solid?

Comment: If you just had a rod suspended by two vertical wires and needed to use virtual work to find the tension in the wires, what would you do? The bike problem is just an obfuscated example of this rod  problem.

Comment: @mikestone so you want to say that as the vertical wires can elongate so can the ground get compressed?

Comment: Yes. Exactly so!